# Documents depending on etexcmds not compiling

Tags: pdftex, texlive

I'm using pdflatex via TeXlive, updated today, on Windows 7 with Texworks as editor, for reference.

When compiling

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etexcmds}
\begin{document}   
    A
\end{document}
```

I get:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (TeX Live 2019/W32TeX) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./etexcmds.tex
LaTeX2e <2019-10-01> patch level 2
(e:/Baseline/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2019/10/25 v1.4k Standard LaTeX document class
(e:/Baseline/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(e:/Baseline/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/etexcmds.sty
(e:/Baseline/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/infwarerr.sty)
! Extra \fi.
l.232 \fi

?
```

Is this a bug in the `oberdiek` package, is my install corrupted or I'm missing something?

Comment: your system is not completly up-to-date. With latex patch level 3 it compiles fine.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Is patch level 3 available in TeXlive? I ran tlmgr update --self and it still says patch level 2.

Comment: not --self, you need to update latex. So run tlmgr update --all (or check first with tlmgr update --list).

Comment: I meant you need to update packages (probably oberdiek and iftex) - I can't see what it outdated on your side, but as latex is too old, there is probably more).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some packages were corrupted (I'm not sure how).

The solution was a forced reinstall of the `oberdiek` bundle via `tlmgr install oberdiek --reinstall`.

As recommended by @UlrikeFischer, an full update via `tlmgr update --all` solved similar issues in other packages.